# Imap idle(false) does't receive all emails

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

i try to implement a mail server that parses emails sent by sensors using sun IMAPFolder and the idle command.

Unfortunately, the idle state closes after 30 minutes and throws a FolderClosedException. To simulate the worst case scenrio in which an email arrives while idle is restarting, I send an test email in the exception body and see if the email is processed.

my code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");



        for(;;) {
            try {
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imap");
                store.connect("localhost", "test@email.db.de", "testpw1");
                Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

                if ((folder == null) || !folder.exists()) {
                    logger.error("folder -inbox- is invalid.");
                    return;
                }

                folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                // Add messageCountListener to listen for new messages
                folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent event) {
                        Message[] messages = event.getMessages();
                        processMessages(messages);                  
                    }               
                });     

                logger.debug("idle start");
                IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) folder;
                f.idle();   //idle state

            } catch (FolderClosedException ex) {
                logger.info("idle timeout");
                long time = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                SendEmail.send("test@email.db.de", "TestSubject", "This mail is sent when idle is off" + df.format(new Date(time));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//endfor

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get two diffrent outputs and I don't know why.

Sometimes the email is processed:

```
02/25/2013 11:45:04.202 DEBUG [Thread-0]    logger     - idle start
02/25/2013 12:15:04.202 INFO  [Thread-0]    logger     - idle timeout
This mail is sent when idle is off 25.02.2013 12:15:04
02/25/2013 12:15:04.235 DEBUG [Thread-0]    logger     - idle start
Got 1 new messages
02/25/2013 12:15:04.267 DEBUG [Thread-0]    logger     - idle start
```

And sometimes not:

```
02/25/2013 10:41:28.895 DEBUG [Thread-0]    logger     - idle start
02/25/2013 11:11:28.898 INFO  [Thread-0]    logger     - idle timeout
This mail is sent when idle is off 25.02.2013 11:11:28
02/25/2013 11:11:28.962 DEBUG [Thread-0]    logger     - idle start
```

My goal is that either the folderClosedException is not thrown anymore or that the email in the catch body is always processed.

How can i achieve this?
Why do i have two types of output here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, my question is relevant after all: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27690838/62821 .  Though there's no answer for it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE only lasts 30 minutes.  After that, the remote server can close your TCP connection.  While the connection is closed, you will not see new email.  (But you should be able to pick it up when you reconnect, by comparing the EXISTS counts and UIDs).

Better practise is to break IDLE at about 29 minutes and reestablish it before the server closes your TCP connection.

You should still handle connections breaks since these can happen for many reasons.

Comment: You can also set up another thread to "poke" the server every 29 minutes, to prevent it from thinking you've been idle for too long.  Calling Folder.getMessageCount should do it.  But as Max says, you still have to handle the case where the connection is dropped.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Could you expain how to handle connection breaks or give some keywords to help me search for the solution?

Comment: Simplest way is to track the highest UID you currently know about.  When you reconnect, do a UID FETCH for anything higher.  (The protocol level command for that would be something like `tag UID FETCH 87:* (<what you want to fetch>)`, where 87 is one highest than the highest UID you've seen before.)  Unfortunately, writing a full IMAP sync algorithm is actually quite the undertaking.  Especially if you want to track deleted items, flags, etc.