# Is there a race condition in IMAP's idle-search-idle?

Tags: imap

I have a bunch of code that does IMAP commands “search, idle, done, search, idle, done, search, ...”.

Is it possible that some messages arrive between search and idle commands and, thus, will only be received by that code after the idle return / timeout?

EDIT1: I tried it with GMail: tested with sleep 60 between the message-processing and IDLE, and IDLE didn't return before timeout even though there were messages; to make sure I didn't miss an event from IDLE, I did a clientside send/recv dump and tried an additional read() before the sending of IDLE after the sleep(); while sending test messaged during the sleep().

EDIT2: Using two connections, one for getting the mail (using 'SEARCH') and another for using IDLE to get instant 'there are new messages' events, avoids the race condition, but [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2245623/jan-kundr%C3%A1t) claims there are some problems with that.

Comment: Regarding the 'claimed problems' of using two connections -- can you provide any further color on that?  Did you end up using two connections and did it work out OK? Any issues with that?

Answer (score 1):

A properly implemented server will notify you of the new messages as soon as you start `IDLE`, if it hasn't already notified you about them in response to some other command.

Comment: Can I assume that gmail isn't a properly implemented server? Or is it more likely that I'm doing something wrong? (I've tested with `sleep 60` between the message-processing and `IDLE` and IDLE didn't return before timeout even though there were messages).

Comment: Many servers may take a minute to return new messages, but I expect you might have missed them as a response to something else since you can get `EXISTS` responses at almost any time.

Comment: no, it does not seem I missed any responses. I did a clientside send/recv dump and tried an additional read() before the sending of IDLE after the sleep(); while sending test messaged during the sleep().